# Is it possible to set an environment variable to the output of a command in cmd.exe

Tags: shell, cmd, backticks

I need to do the equivalent of

```
set ENVAR=`some-command`
```

In a windows/cmd.exe script.  Cygwin is not an option.

For bonus marks: Is there some cmd.exe equivalent of backticks in general?

Comment: I have a third-party program that calls cmd.exe with a script and checks the CAUSE environment variable after the script finishes.  I can't use another shell directly.

Comment: Just FYI, how to do this in Linux and Unix: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/493081/how-to-create-an-environment-variable-that-is-the-output-of-a-command

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A quick and dirty way would be redirecting it to a file and then reading this, e.g.

```
some-command>out.txt
set /p ENVAR=<out.txt
```

I think `for` can also help you, but I don't remember the exact syntax. Try something like

```
for /f "usebackq" %x in (`some-command`) do set ENVAR=%x
```

I probably forgot some `token` or `delim` in the options...

Answer (score 3):

Not "probably", it is absolutely a must to specify "delims=" (it means "no delimiters"), unless you want your variable to only contain up to first space or tab of the input data.

It is recommended to specify "delims=" as the last option to avoid potential confusion in options perception by the operator and by the shell.

I.e.

```
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%a IN (`cygpath.exe -u "%~1"`) DO (
    SET CMDNAME=%%~a
    SHIFT
)
```

See [SS64 article on FOR /F](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html).

Comment: The `delims=` option must be the last one in case you want to specify a space as delimiter. The string `"delims= usebackq"` would define no delimiter, but `"usebackq delims= "` defines the space…

Comment: Right you are. I guess my source was more from a "best practice" camp. I will edit my answer appropriately.